# How to convert a list of dictionaries to a Bunch object

Tags: python, bunch

I have a list of the following dictionaries:

```
[{'Key': 'tag-key-0', 'Value': 'value-0'},
 {'Key': 'tag-key-1', 'Value': 'value-1'},
 {'Key': 'tag-key-2', 'Value': 'value-2'},
 {'Key': 'tag-key-3', 'Value': 'value-3'},
 {'Key': 'tag-key-4', 'Value': 'value-4'}]
```

Is there an elegant way to convert it to a Bunch object?

```
Bunch(tag-key-0='value-0', tag-key-1='value-1', tag-key-2='value-2', tag-key-3='value-3', tag-key-4='value-4')
```

My current solution is:

```
from bunch import Bunch

tags_dict = {}
for tag in actual_tags:
    tags_dict[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']

Bunch.fromDict(tags_dict)
```

Comment: `Bunch(tags_dict)`? am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @Guy, but can I avoid that for loop that coverts list of dicts to dict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` of `Bunch.values()` from `actual_tags`:

```
actual_tags = [{'Key': 'tag-key-0', 'Value': 'value-0'},
               {'Key': 'tag-key-1', 'Value': 'value-1'},
               {'Key': 'tag-key-2', 'Value': 'value-2'},
               {'Key': 'tag-key-3', 'Value': 'value-3'},
               {'Key': 'tag-key-4', 'Value': 'value-4'}]

from bunch import Bunch

tags_dict = Bunch(map(Bunch.values, actual_tags))

print(tags_dict)
print(type(tags_dict))
```

Output:

```
tag-key-0: value-0
tag-key-1: value-1
tag-key-2: value-2
tag-key-3: value-3
tag-key-4: value-4

<class 'bunch.Bunch'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using a version of Bunch that is different than the one that you get via `pip install bunch`, the Bunch class has no `from_dict` classmethod.

Using `Bunch(tags_dict)` appears to work:

```
>>> from bunch import Bunch

>>> actual_tags = [{'Key': 'tag-key-0', 'Value': 'value-0'},
...  {'Key': 'tag-key-1', 'Value': 'value-1'},
...  {'Key': 'tag-key-2', 'Value': 'value-2'},
...  {'Key': 'tag-key-3', 'Value': 'value-3'},
...  {'Key': 'tag-key-4', 'Value': 'value-4'}]

>>> tags_dict = {tag['Key']: tag['Value'] for tag in actual_tags}

>>> print(Bunch(tags_dict))
tag-key-0: value-0
tag-key-1: value-1
tag-key-2: value-2
tag-key-3: value-3
tag-key-4: value-4
```

One thing to note: Bunch does not appear to be actively maintained - its last commit was [over 10 years ago](https://github.com/dsc/bunch), and it does not seem to be fully compatible with Python 3. [AttrDict](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/) appears to be more recent, but it is also inactive.

Answer (score 1):

Import:

```
from bunch import Bunch
```

Option 1:

```
b = Bunch({t['Key']:t['Value'] for t in actual_tags})
```

Option 2:

```
b = Bunch.fromDict({t['Key']:t['Value'] for t in actual_tags})
```